# Scroll to top of table view in iOS 11

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11

I have a table view and I want it to always be scrolled to the top when it first appears. The following code used to work fine but it no longer does anything in iOS 11. How do you scroll to the top of a table view in iOS 11?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];    
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use  `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method 
as -

**ObjC**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:true];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:true];
}
```

**SWIFT 4**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
    }
```

You can also set custom row in `indexpath` by putting various row & section value.

Comment: This actually scrolls to the top row, but if the tableview has a header by itself, this wont work, because it will scroll to the first row and keeps the header hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's in `viewWillAppear`, I wonder if you are doing this in the wrong place (since the view and table hasn't been displayed yet).  Try doing this in `viewDidAppear`.

On my side, when I wire up `[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated: NO]` to an IBAction, it dutifully moves to the very first (or 0-th) cell in the table (without animating the scroll), so that call definitely still works in iOS 11.

Comment: Yes, it works in `-viewDidAppear:` but I want the table view to be scrolled to the top before it appears. This is what seems broken in iOS 11.